# ClassCastException with JBoss cache

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss5.x, jboss-cache

We're using JBoss SOA 5.3.1 with JBoss-cache with a hibernate 2nd level cache.

- All works fine for simple entites, except for a nested type com.example.GUID;
- GUID lives in a CommonUtil.jar, which is included in each ESB.
- Other nested values, like Joda DateTime instances work fine between ESBs, but the joda-time.jar lives in the central JBoss/lib folder, and thus a global class-loader is used.
- The problem occurs when an ESB tries to retrieve a value from the cache another ESB has previously loaded, because the cached GUID class type is a different instance a ClassCastException is thrown when Hibernate tries to call setGuid() using it.
- I've tried setting hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries = true, but this does not fix the issue

My question is, how can we configure JBoss cache and/or jboss-classloading.xml to share this auxiliary non-entity class GUID between ESBs to avoid the problem.

The exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of com.example.Equipment.guid
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:351)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.setPropertyValues(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:232)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.setPropertyValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3690)
    at org.hibernate.cache.entry.CacheEntry.assemble(CacheEntry.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.cache.entry.CacheEntry.assemble(CacheEntry.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.assembleCacheEntry(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:542)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:397)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:908)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1030)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:987)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:896)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2455)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2440)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2316)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2311)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1192)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@76e6d130
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor437.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter.set(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:65)
    ... 59 more
```

The entity

```
import com.example.GUID

@Entity
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Table(name = "EQUIPMENT")
public class Equipment implements Serializable {

    private GUID guid;

    @Column(name = "GUID")
    @Type(type = "com.example.PersistentGUID")
    public GUID getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure... are you talking about EJBs or ESBs?

Comment: Move the CommonUtil.jar to the jboss/lib folder too then? Although the classloading varies a lot between JBoss 4, 5, 6 and 7 that the JBoss Community Forums might give you a better answer.

Comment: It's looking like that's the only solution, however we're a large project 40+ devs, and coming to the end. I'm trying to avoid any disruptive changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer we found to this, after many support emails to RedHat was to change the GUID type to a string.